# Автоматическое открытие подключаемых PDB после перезагрузки БД

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracle18c

После установки БД проблем с подключением PDB не наблюдал. Переустановил Windows и заново Oracle. Теперь, каждый раз при перезагрузке Windows, мне приходится открывать PDB, так как её статус `mounted`.

Я нашел как с помощью триггера подключать все PDB при старте, но я не помню, чтобы я его использовал в прошлый раз.

Kак подключать PDB без триггера при перезагрузке БД?

Comment: смотрите в сторону что настроено spfile
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start001.htm#ADMIN10063

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с 12.1.0.2 в `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE` добавлена клауза [`SAVE STATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_admin.htm#ADMIN14251).

```
SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 PDB1                           READ WRITE NO
         4 PDB2                           MOUNTED

SQL> shutdown immediate
```

После рестарта все PDB остаются закрытыми:

```
SQL> startup
SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 PDB1                           MOUNTED
         4 PDB2                           MOUNTED
```

Зафиксируйте состояние PDB (всех, если вместо имени указать `ALL`):

```
SQL> alter pluggable database pdb1 open;
SQL> alter pluggable database pdb1 save state;
```

После рестарта желаемые PDB откроются автоматически:

```
    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 PDB1                           READ WRITE NO
         4 PDB2                           MOUNTED
```